# gnuplot not showing the rowstacked histogram properly

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Following is my script.

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstack gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.8
set grid ytics linestyle 1
set key autotitle columnheader
set key below horizontal right
set ylabel "Overhead (%)"
set xlabel "Benchmark"

plot newhistogram "bm1" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 2:xtic(1), '' u 3, '' u 4, \
newhistogram "bm2" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 5:xtic(1) notitle, '' u 6 notitle, '' u 7 notitle, \
newhistogram "bm3" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 8:xtic(1) notitle, '' u 9 notitle, '' u 10 notitle, \
newhistogram "bm4" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 11:xtic(1) notitle, '' u 12 notitle, '' u 13 notitle
```

And following is my data.

```
Threads "Overhead 1" "Overhead 2" "Overhead 3"
w1   6  47 58    8 0 0   15 4 45    12   5  5           
w2   4  6  6     5 0 2   1 3 2      10  20  30
```

The graph that I get is shown below. Note the problem with the right bar of the 4th benchmark (`bm4`, `w2`). Why the bar has an offset? I don't understand this.

[image]

Comment: I've submitted a bug report.  It looks like a regression, although I can't say when exactly gnuplot regressed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug/regression.  I made minimal changes to your script to get gnuplot to stop complaining about the titles:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstack gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.8
set grid ytics linestyle 1
set key below horizontal right
set ylabel "Overhead (%)"
set xlabel "Benchmark"

plot newhistogram "bm1" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 2:xtic(1) title columnhead(2), '' u 3 title columnhead(3), '' u 4 title columnhead(4), \
     newhistogram "bm2" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 5:xtic(1) notitle, '' u 6 notitle, '' u 7 notitle, \
     newhistogram "bm3" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 8:xtic(1) notitle, '' u 9 notitle, '' u 10 notitle, \
     newhistogram "bm4" lt 2, 'plot1.txt' u 11:xtic(1) notitle, '' u 12 notitle, '' u 13 notitle
```

Here's the graph (plotted to the postscript terminal) using gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0 (Plotted on OS-X 10.5).:

[image: Plotted with gnuplot 4.6.0]

Here's the same script, but with gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 2:

[image: Plotted with gnuplot 4.4.2]

*The same behavior happens if I plot using the png terminal*

Comment: Yes it works, though it still doesn't work with wgnuplot (gnuplot in windows) which I was using. Seems like there is a bug in there. In my ubuntu VM, it works fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user1018562  -- Here's the link to the bug report I filed if you're interested:  ( https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=102055&aid=3566662&group_id=2055 )

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I just came across the same issue, and after hours of searching for a solution, I realized that windows gnuplot has a problem when plotting stacked histograms for files with header (by header I mean the first line of the file that contains the name of the columns).

So, a quick workaround for this problem would be to remove the headers from source file.

It worked for me.